# Yii2 // Model as Model attribute

Tags: php, validation, yii2, models, composite

actually im working on a project, where i want to have all DB-tables as Models. But now im stucking at one Point. 
Lets say i have a "Master"-Table where many different relations are defined like the following (easy example):

Human has one heart; Human has one brain... and so on... 
Is it possible, to fill up the Master-Model with other Models? 
In PHP it would looks like that:

```
$human = new Human();
$human->heart = new Heart(); 
$human->brain = new Brain();
```

Finally i want to say:

```
$human-save(TRUE);
```

to VALIDATE all relational models AND save all relational data and the human object in DB.

Is that possible? I cant find something like that on the whole internet O_o.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the DB table model relationships, they usually also enforce them upon all writing attempts, so I am not at all clear in understanding where you want to validate what. On DB level if supported the closest thing I see there is the TRANSACTION block (that either fails or succeeds). Are you searching a method from the Yi framework? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, i'll try to make it clear to you. 
If i call $human->save(true) with "true" parameter, i enforce the Model-Validation. So my first question is: if i have different models in one Model (like example above), are the "submodels" getting validated, too?
Second question: 
How can i access the goal to have a model in a model? What do i have to do in my main-model and in my submodels to achive this?

Comment: @jiGL The Model class in yii2 doesn't have `save()` method. Are you using ActiveRecord or some other ORM implementation?

Comment: @Maxim
Yes, sorry! My models inherit from ActiveRecord!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you following approach:

1. Let's say you have same relation names as property names for nested objects (some rule needed to call `$model->link()` method)
2. Declare common class for Models with nested Models (for example ActiveRecordWithNestedModels)
3. Override in common class methods `save` and `validate` to perform cascade for these operations  (using reflection)
4. Let your models will inherit this common class

**Or**, as an alternative for overriding `validate` method, you can build some suitable implementation for `rules` method in common class.

This common class can looks as follows (**this is a simple draft, not tested, just to show the conception**):

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class ActiveRecordWithNestedModels extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $saveResult = parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);

        $class = new \ReflectionClass($this);

        foreach ($class->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $property) {
            $propertyValue = $property->getValue($this);
            if (!empty($propertyValue) && is_subclass_of($propertyValue, ActiveRecord::className())) {
                /* @var ActiveRecord $nestedModel */
                $nestedModel = $propertyValue;
                $nestedModel->save($runValidation);
                $relation = $property->name;
                $this->link($relation, $nestedModel);
            }
        }

        return $saveResult;
    }

    public function validate($attributeNames = null, $clearErrors = true)
    {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass($this);

        foreach ($class->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $property) {
            $propertyValue = $property->getValue($this);
            if (!empty($propertyValue) && is_subclass_of($propertyValue, ActiveRecord::className())) {
                /* @var ActiveRecord $nestedModel */
                $nestedModel = $propertyValue;

                if (!$nestedModel->validate(null, $clearErrors)) {
                    array_push($this->errors, [
                        $property->name => $nestedModel->errors
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }

        parent::validate($attributeNames, $clearErrors);

        if ($this->hasErrors()) return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Then your models can looks like this:

```
class Heart extends ActiveRecordWithNestedModels
{

}

class Human extends ActiveRecordWithNestedModels
{
    /* @var Heart $heart */
    public $heart = null;

    /**
     * The relation name will be 'heart', same as property `heart'
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getHeart()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Heart::className(), ['id', 'heart_id']);
    }
}
```

And (in theory) you can do:

```
$human = new Human();
$human->heart = new Heart();
$human->save();
```

**P.S.** here can be many complex details in further implementation, as for example

- using transactions to rollback `save` if some child object fails save
- overriding `delete`
- serving `one-to-many` and `many-to-many` relations
- skip cascade if property has no corresponding relation
- serving `$attributeNames` in cascade operations
- etc

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what i was looking for... thank you!!
Thought it would be a little bit easier or something similar exists out of the box in yii2. Anyways thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can override `ActiveModel` `Save` method, according to [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#inserting-updating-data):

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
{
    if ($this->getIsNewRecord()) {
        $save = $this->insert($runValidation, $attributeNames);
    } else {
        $save = $this->update($runValidation, $attributeNames) !== false;
    }

    /* Condition Work if heart and brain is also ActiveModel then 
       you can trigger save method on these models as well
       or you can add your custom logic as well.  
    */

    if($this->heart && $this->brain) {
         return $this->heart->save() && $this->brain->save();
    }

    return $save;

}
```